# How to display a generic text inside a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a textarea/textbox which dynamically gets url from the database. Right now the textbox is showing full url address and does not look good. What I was trying to get is use some generic text like "click here for more info". I tried `placeholder` but does not work. I need to use generic text and when link go to the link it gets from database. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```html
//just for test
//this text area is getting values from db(url)
<a id="aurl" target="_blank" > <textarea id="evnt"
        type="text" name="event" cols="40" disabled></textarea></a>
```

Comment: You should not place a `<textarea>` inside `<a>`.

Comment: Is there a scenario where someone would be typing into the textbox? It sounds like you just want to dynamically set the URL for a link and offer the link for the user to click. If so, no need to use a textbox -- just set the href on the link.

Comment: why negative on my question?

Comment: block line elements together

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes any sense to wrap a `<textarea>` element in an `<a>` anchor tag. A textarea is expecting user input, where as an anchor tag is for linking you to somewhere else. Could just use a normal hyperlink as below?

```
<a href="[url_from_db]">click here for more info</a>
```